# Store a 2D array within another array -- Java

Tags: java, arrays

I need to be able to store a 2D boolean array within another array, which is as follows...

```
   boolean[][] Player = new boolean[1][2];       

   Object[] Game = new Object[1];

   Player[0][0] = true;
   Player[0][1] = false;

   Game[0] = Player[0][0];
```

I need to be able to set each Game[] index with a Player, but what I have above doesn't work. Is there any way to insert an array within an array?

Comment: Please rename your variable, it's very confusing. Until now I still think `Player` is a class.. I just can't get it out of my mind :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to store the 2D array in `Game[0]` then you should do

```
Game[0] = Player;
```

---

Other points:

- I would suggest you create a `Player` class:

  ```
  class Player {
      boolean flag1;
      boolean flag2;
  }
  ```

  instead of creating arrays of booleans.

  Your player array (`Game`) would then have the type `Player[]`.
- Let variable names start with lower case and class names start with capital case.
- If you *really* want to use arrays, I'd suggest you change the type of `Game` to `boolean[][][]`.

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to set into `Game[0]` field `boolean` value. Do this

```
Game[0] = Player;
```

if you want to store array into another array. And my advice to U: if U want to become a good java programmer write good code using [JCC](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconvtoc-136057.html). Name of non final variable begins with lowercase letter so instead of `Game` and `Player`, in java so call classes, use `game` and `player`.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to store each player in game array index you should write:

```
Game[0] = Player;
```